# How to ignore certain parameters in argv?

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that empties files by opening them in the write mode. It should also be possible to use wildcards like *, but in this case I want it to ignore the file itself, so the program doesn't delete itself.

To test this out I've tried:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

     for (int i = 1; i <= argc; ++i) {
         if(strcmp(argv[i], "empty"))
             printf("File detected\n");

     }
}
```

I then run

`./empty empty`

I get a segmentation fault and "File detected" is not printed. Why is that?

Comment: `i <= argc;` should be `i < argc;` The element `argv[argc]` is always `NULL` (a sentinel) so you are dereferencing a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: init i with i=0 and, compare with i <argc. Note : i=0 will include the program name ./empty

Comment: What should your program do if it is called by a link or if the user renamed it? You can't be sure that it always has the name "empty".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing at `argv[argc]` which is `NULL` and passing `NULL` to `strcmp` causes the segfault..

change

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= argc; ++i) {
```

to

```
 for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
```

---

`strcmp` returns `0` if strings are matching.

```
     if(strcmp(argv[i], "empty"))
         printf("File detected\n");
```

should be

```
 if(strcmp(argv[i], "empty") == 0)
     printf("File detected\n");
```

Comment: Well, that gets rid of the segmentation fault. But the "File detected" string is still not printed.